# Cookiebot finding TS# cookie

Tags: cookies

As part of the new GDPR requirements in europe I've used cookiebot to show visitors what cookies we use on our site.

It's managed to show us what all but 1 cookie is used for. The cookie is called TS# and in their example stores this information:
0ei8sug22mj561h32e087mb5f2

The cookiebot report doesn’t mention CraftSessionId which has this data:
p2q9d364sf2abu1mmd5vi8rd54

May be a coincidence but they're both 26 characters long.

Does anyone know what the TS# cookie is used for, if it is a Craft CMS cookie?

Comment: I've never seen that cookie before on a Craft site. Might be something (JavaScript?) that's been added to the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

Craft doesn't natively set a cookie named `TS#`, so it's either coming from something in your front-end templates or possibly from a plugin you've got installed.

You can read about the `CraftSessionId` cookie and all other cookies that Craft uses by default here: https://craftcms.com/support/how-does-craft-use-cookies